# Angular 4 Internationalization

Tags: angular

How to Implement Internationalization (1i8n) on button click for multiple languages (at least 4 languages) using Angular 4?

I tried the [plunker](http://%20https://embed.plnkr.co/TE7raLGC9pvYfaRu6Syg/) example but its not working:

Comment: please add plunker which you have tried

Comment: try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/internationalization?file=src%2Fconfig%2Ftranslate.ts

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are mainly 2 localization strategies currently in Angular (7).

**i18n** currently (I belive) only supports static localization: the language of the application you write, will be decided and rendered upon **build time.** That means, you cannot change the app with a button click on-the-fly: you must build **multiple instances with different languages** and change between them (for instance, serve them with prefix url, and force the user to navigate to the other one: `www.my-page.com/ger/main` -> `www.my-page.com/eng/main`

**Dynamic localization** is where you can change the strings, labels etc. translation durring **runtime.** For that, you need an external libary. The most popular one is [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). Please check it out, it can dynamically load language dictionaries, and translate strings on the spot. This way, you can bind strings like `{{'a-string-key' | translate }}` or in ts 
`this.label = _translateService.instant('a-string-key');` and change what these render with `_translateService.setLanguage('ger');`